# Evaluating the limit $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left( 1+ \frac{ 4-\sin(x) }{ n } \right)^n $, which is apparently related to $e$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$
> \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left( 1+ \frac{ 4-\sin(x) }{ n } \right)^n
> $$

I see a VERY close relation to limit $$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left( 1+ \frac{ 1 }{ n } \right)^n,
$$ related to the definition of $e$, and I think that's what I have to do here but I'm not sure where to go about for this. Any ideas? Is there perhaps some way to manipulate this definition to get the limit, possibly?

Answer (score 2):

You may use, as $u \to 0$, the Taylor expansion:
$$
\ln (1+u)=u+O(u^2)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
\ln\left( 1+ \frac{ 4-\sin(x) }{ n } \right)=\frac{ 4-\sin(x) }{ n }+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
$$ and
$$
n\ln\left( 1+ \frac{ 4-\sin(x) }{ n } \right)=4-\sin(x)+O\left(\frac1n\right)
$$ and the limit is easier to obtain.

Comment: It's absurd. Everything I do gives me 4-sin(x) too!!! But wolfram gives me 0 >.< .

Comment: Wolfarm isnot right, for example let $x=\pi$

Comment: Wow ._. ... That's a first. I've never seen wolfram wrong yet...

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty Are you sure you're bracketing your notation correctly? If you write $\log(u)^n$, Wolfram might interpret this as $(\log u)^n$ rather than $\log (u^n)$; the limit of the former expression (where $u$ is as in the question) really is $0$, but presumably by your notation you mean the latter.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty Indeed, compare http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn+%5Cto+%5Cinfty%7D+%5Clog%281+%2B+%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bn%7D%29%5En vs. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bn+%5Cto+%5Cinfty%7D+%5Clog%28%281+%2B+%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bn%7D%29%5En%29

Comment: Wow. The brackets made all the difference -.- ...

Answer (score 1):

$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left( 1+ \frac{ 4-\sin(x) }{ n } \right)^n
=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\ln\left( 1+ \frac{ 4-\sin(x) }{ n } \right)^{\frac{n}{ 4-\sin(x)}\times { 4-\sin(x)}}=ln e^{4-\sin(x)}=4-sinx$

Comment: That is literally what I did. I just trusted wolfram way to much ._. ...

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty just ask W|A about the injectivity of $f(x)=\ln x$ and the illusion will end.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Set $$m := \frac{n}{4 - \sin x}$$ and rewrite the limit in terms of $m$.

Comment: I did all of that but I get the limit is 2-sin(x) and not 0 as wolfram gives.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty You should include what you've done so far in your original question, so that you can get answers better tailored toward your situation.

Comment: No I got it. Wolfram is just being stupid with notation.

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty, not trying to be argumentative, but I've read your comments: Wolfram is not being stupid with notations. Notations might not be ambiguous to human eye, but often are to computers. Correct bracketing is important, especially to computers.

Comment: Fair enough haha. I wasn't trying to be rude at all :) .

Answer (score 0):

One really important step is missing: how do we justify the interchange of limits and $\log$ function? This is possible because $\log$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$. Once you've done that the rest is just algebra as others explained.